# Pentaho kettle - How to rotate log file/custom log formatter when using kitchen.bat

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using kitchen.bat to run the kettle job (added in the windows task scheduler).
But I also need to monitor the exception generated by the ETL above. Currently, I'm thinking using python scripts to monitor "result = (false)" or "error" in the logs, but the logs generated by the kitchen cannot rotate which can be quite big for python to process.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to do any configuration on the log file generated by kitchen, like rotating the file either by date and customizing the log format. (https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.1/Products/Use_Command_Line_Tools_to_Run_Transformations_and_Jobs).

Comment: can you please re-write the question with specification like what you wanted to achieve? you are also referring documentation of very old version of pentaho

Comment: @HelpingHand.. edited! Please check if this is ok now

Comment: in pentaho we have 7 types of logs, like : error,no-log,basic,detail,debug,etc.. i don't understand what is rotating however you can use the suitable log type to capture the details according to your requirement.

Comment: @HelpingHand..，rotating logs by day are like logs split by day. For example, logs at 2020-11-03 are saved in log_xxx_20201103.log, logs at 2020-11-02 are saved in log_xxx_20201102.log. I can specify date in job level log but cannot do this by using kitchen.bat. I'm wondering if this can be done in kettle

Comment: checkout this - https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Setup/Administration/Performance_Monitoring/PDI_Logging